# Проблема с Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position) в Unty

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Как сделать в моей 2д игре, так, чтобы игра не отслеживала моё палец (тач), когда я нажимаю на кнопки ходьбы. В моей игре, оружие персонажа следит за касанием экрана, целится туда, где находится палец. Но когда нажимаю кнопки ходьбы, то смотрит туда же. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы отслеживалось нажатие на элемент Canvas -> Panel,  Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShootPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        LookAt();
    }

    void LookAt()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            Vector2 direction = new Vector2(touchPosition.x - transform.position.x, touchPosition.y - transform.position.y);
            transform.right = direction;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у Unity есть система интерфейсных событий [EventSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/EventSystem.html). Суть её в том, что она позволяет отслеживать различные действия ввода прилагательно к конкретным игровым объектам.

В вашем случае помогут два интерфейса этой системы [IPointerDownHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) и [IDragHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IDragHandler.html). Метод первого вызывается, когда "поинтер" (тач/курсор) опускается на объект, на котором висит данный скрипт, метод второго вызывается каждый кадр, в течении которого палец двигается по этому объекту.

И так, у нас есть два инструмента. Как их использовать? Добавить на сцену EventSystem (она так же добавится сама при добавлении первого Canvas), написать класс, который реализует оба этих интерфейса и который будет отслеживать нажатие игрока на поле и сообщать о нём всем заинтересованным, добавить этот класс на ваше игровое поле.

Выглядеть это будет примерно так:

```
public class ShootPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    LookAtHandler _handler;

    private void Start()
    {
        _handler.OnTouchEvent += LookAt;
    }

    void LookAt(Vector3 touchPosition)
    {
        Vector2 direction = new Vector2(touchPosition.x - transform.position.x, touchPosition.y - transform.position.y);
        transform.right = direction;
    }
}


class LookAtHandler : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IDragHandler
{
    public event Action<Vector3> OnTouchEvent = delegate { };

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        OnTouchCalculate();
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        OnTouchCalculate();
    }

    void OnTouchCalculate()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
            var touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(touch.position);
            OnTouchEvent(touchPosition);
        }
    }
}
```

Т.е. у нас есть класс LookAtHandler - он реализует ранее описанные интерфейсы и реагирует на события нажатия(он должен висеть на вашей панели). При каждом нажатии он вызывает у себя событие, в которое передаёт рассчитанную точку нажатия.

Так же у нас есть ваш класс ShootPoint - он подписывается на событие handler-а на старте и отвечает за то, чтобы повернуть юнит в нужную нам точку, когда срабатывает событие нажатия.

Comment: Всё равно следит за пальцем вне панели. Я ведь правильно всё сделал?: 1) К Class LookAtHandler добавил Monobehaviour, этот скрипт прикрепил к панели.  2) А class Shoot Point к объекту, который должен вращаться. 3) К LookAtHandler _handler; в компонентах перетащил туда Panel

Comment: PinPin, да, всё верно. Следить должно только когда вы касаетесь этой панели. Судя по тому, что оно таки поворачивается - всё сделано правильно. У вас случайно старый скрипт нигде висеть не остался? Попробуйте в редакторе во время выполнения выключить объект с панелью - будет ли оно следить? Что вы имеете ввиду под "вне панели"? Панель у вас не на весь экран? Если в иерархии во время выполнения выбрать объект EventSystem справа снизу можно смотреть текущие данные в нём, в том числе на какой объект наведён курсор и прочую информацию

Comment: Надеюсь не надоел вам, можете ответить на пару вопросов? 1) Как выстрелить в сторону моего Тача?
    Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
2) Как сделать так, чтобы оружие, отражалось в противположную сторону, когда палец находится левее персонажа?

Comment: @PinPin, 1) вам нужен класс, который в update будет двигать пулю между двумя точками или от точки старта в направлении какой-то точки. Этот класс вешать на пулю и после спауна передавать ему координаты куда двигаться.  2) Сравнивайте position.x касания и position.x персонажа. Если первый меньше - устанавливайте оружие rotation (0, 180, 0), если больше (0,0,0). Или если у вас SpriteRenderer, а не Image, то можно просто менять на true/false параметр FlipX